# May I get my question opened as I finished the prerequisite of working code?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I have finished my code and awaiting a review. It would be appreciated if it was opened:

[Generate any n^2 x n^2 Sudoku in poly-time](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220967/verify-any-n2-x-n2-sudoku-grid)

Answer (score 2):

See the last section of the Help Center documentation: [*What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) -

> #### Why are some questions marked "closed"?
>
> Questions are marked `[on hold]` for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question. If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will automatically be placed in a [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/341145) to be considered for reopening.

Your post should have come through the [Reopen Queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/117173), though you may not have permission to view that until you earn more privileges. If enough users vote to reopen it then it will be re-opened.

Also relevant: the last paragraph of

### [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) > [Privileges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) > [Cast close and reopen votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

> Similarly, the reopen queue will contain any post that currently has an active reopen vote. Users can vote to reopen, edit the question (which includes a reopen vote), or leave the question closed. A certain number of Leave Closed votes will again kick the question out of the queue and begin the reopen vote aging process, and of course, another reopen vote will put it back into the queue. Questions which get edited within 5 days of being closed will automatically show up in the reopen queue for review. Questions which have had a revision will add an extra tab at the top so that you can quickly view the revision. Like the close votes queue, questions which were closed as duplicates will still list the duplicates in the tabs above.